# Scraping a link in PHP not working, but link ok in browser

Tags: php, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape the contents of [this](https://secure-admin.booking.com/booking.html?bn=600861417&hotel_id=279299&l%20ang=en&code=049ae718b3d22164934cf621bece92ad&message_num=1) page using PHP.

Link works in a browser, but when using `curl` or `get_file_contents`, the [booking.com](http://booking.com) website reports that the link is not valid. I'm not sure if this is a firewall problem with my hosting company reg-123?

Can anyone help please?

Code being used is as follows:

```
$url='https://secure-admin.booking.com/booking.html?bn=600861417&hotel_id=279299&l ang=en&code=049ae718b3d22164934cf621bece92ad&message_num=1';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 9.0; WIndows NT 9.0; en-US)'); 

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

Comment: You should ask the admins at booking.com if they are okay with you scraping their site. Perhaps they intentionally block such requests.

Comment: You should definitely add http://www.php.net/curl_getinfo to your code to see details of the request and response to be able to debug this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not `get_file_contents`, but `file_get_contents`:
And it just returns the contents perfectly! I tried it. Also I noticed in your URL there is an unwanted white space, just after `279299279299&l ang`

```
<?php
$contents = file_get_contents("https://secure-admin.booking.com/booking.html?bn=600861417&hotel_id=279299&lang=en&code=049ae718b3d22164934cf621bece92ad&message_num=1");

echo $contents;
?>
```

Comment: Ah - so simple!!!  Thank you so much, this could have taken me hours to find.